# Check if string is empty in Nunjucks?

Tags: nunjucks, eleventy

Using Eleventy with Nunjucks, and need to check if a front matter field is empty and if a string is empty. It would be the same thing as isEmpty() in JS. Does Nunjucks support this functionality? It seems like a pretty simple and common feature, but I've looked all over the docs and StackOverflow but can't find any mention or example.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I tested like so:

```html
---
name: ray
age: 
---


{% if age %}
age has a value
{% else %}
age has NO value
{% endif %}
```

And it worked as expected, I got: "age has NO value".